# Why doesn'e send() function return 0 in this situation?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

i wrote a sample of socket,both server and client program.At server,when it accept the connection,it will close it at once.At client ,it will connect to server,then sleep for 1 secs,and then send something to server.
What confuse me is why send function  doesn't return 0 ？The code is below

```
Client.py
import socket
import time
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
  clientsocket.connect(("127.0.0.1",8886))
  ret = clientsocket.send(("Hello world").encode('utf-8'))
  time.sleep(1.0)
  print("All send bytes is {}".format(ret))
except socket.error as msg:
  print(msg)


Server.py 
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(("127.0.0.1",8886))
serversocket.listen(5)

while True:
  clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()
  clientsocket.shutdown(2)
  clientsocket.close()
```

Send function return 11 not   0.after connection established,i close it immediately.but client sends data successfully.that confuses me

Comment: Have you read the manual?

Comment: @klutt i read the document,nothing helpful.

Comment: Really? "Returns the number of bytes sent." https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

Comment: @klutt i know that.after connection  established,i close it immediately.but client sends data successfully.that confuses me